# MySQL data type for movie times

Tags: python, mysql

I have chapter times in the form of HH:MM:SS. I am parsing them from a document, and I will have times as a string in the format of '00:12:14'. How would I store this in a mysql column, and then retrieve it in the required format to be able to:

- 1) order by time;
- 2) convert to a string in the above format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have such a simple task, I choose a simple solution: I would choose the python `datetime.time` module (see: [datetime.time](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#time-objects)) and store a [TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html) object using `strftime`.

Loading it back in is a little painful as you would have to split your string at `:` and then pass the values to the `time` constructor. Example:

```
def load(timestr):
    hours,minutes,seconds = timestr.split(":")
    return datetime.time(hours,minutes,seconds)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at the MySQL time type.  It will allow you to sort and format as you wish.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html) type.

It allows "time values to be represented in several formats, such as quoted strings or as numbers, depending on the exact type of the value and other factors." In addition, you can perform [various functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to manipulate the time.